# Performing a function after x time

Tags: arduino

What can I use to perform a function in the loop if none of the other conditions in the loop and their code have been executed after a certain amount of time? Can it be done with a delay, or is there some other function?

Answer (score 13):

I don't think it's possible to implement since the Arduino does not have an internal clock.

**EDIT :**
It is possible to use the [millis()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/millis) function to calculate an amount of time since the start of the board:

```
unsigned long previousMillis = 0; // last time update
long interval = 2000; // interval at which to do something (milliseconds)

void setup(){
}

void loop(){
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
     previousMillis = currentMillis;  

     // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: A tutor mentioned it's possible to add to my code, but didn't explain how. I've heard about the millis() function but don't quite understand it, does it start a timer when you call it? Or does it just show the elapsed time from the start of the loop?

Comment: It just show the elapsed time from the start of the board. This number will overflow (go back to zero), after approximately 50 days (source: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/millis)

Answer (score 6):

Try arduino timer interrupts. No need for external libraries or even additional hardware, since the processor can be considered a clock... at 16 MHz.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void setup ()
{

  // INITIALIZE TIMER INTERRUPTS
  cli(); // disable global interrupts

  TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
  TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B

  OCR1A = 15624; // set compare match register to desired timer count. 16 MHz with 1024 prescaler = 15624 counts/s
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12); // turn on CTC mode. clear timer on compare match

  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10); // Set CS10 and CS12 bits for 1024 prescaler
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);

  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // enable timer compare interrupt

  sei(); // enable global interrupts

}

// TIMER VECTOR, gets called once a second (depends on prescaler and match register)
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  // do your timeing based stuff here
}
```

[need more info on interrupts?](http://www.engblaze.com/microcontroller-tutorial-avr-and-arduino-timer-interrupts/)

Comment: The linked article is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The `millis()` function normally works well enough for this, unless you want the time-out to survive a restart of the arduino.

I would implement a Timer class that keeps track of the last time `some_condition` was met:

```
class Timer
{
public:
    Timer(void);
    void set_max_delay(unsigned long v);
    void set(void);
    boolean check(void);
private:
    unsigned long max_delay;
    unsigned long last_set;
};

Timer::Timer(void)
{
    max_delay = 3600000UL; // default 1 hour
}

void Timer::set_max_delay(unsigned long v)
{
    max_delay = v;
    set();
}

void Timer::set()
{
    last_set = millis();
}

boolean Timer::check()
{
    unsigned long now = millis();
    if (now - last_set > max_delay) {
        last_set = now;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Timer timer;

void setup()
{
   timer.set_max_delay(60000); // 1 minute
}

void loop()
{
   boolean some_condition = false;
   if (some_condition) {
       timer.set();
   }
   if (timer.check()) {
      // nothing happened for a long time
   }
   delay(500);
}
```

As long as `some_condition` is not met the `last_set` value of the Timer does not get updated. Eventually resulting in the `check()` to return `true` (once per interval, as `check()` sets the `last_set` value)

If the checking needs to survive a processor reset, then you need a battery backed-up (real-time) clock and store and retrieve `last_set` from EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the [Metro library](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/Metro), which lets you do recurring timed events. You can change the frequency of the timer within the loop, if that's a desirable thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many versions of these timer routines, all assume that if you've reached or exceeded the timeout you reset the timer variable from millis(). Wrong. What if you've been busy and are well past the timeslot.. the lot has now been stretched.

So lets say we want to do sometihng every 50ms.   Lets say we got held up and it is now 55ms after last check.. we check... sure enough we overwrite the timer variable so we'll get a match in 50ms. but now we're 5ms behind. We need to compensate for being late and what happens if there is an overflow at this point....

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/time

Answer (score 1):

A timer that will survive a restart of the Arduino is impossbile to implement without external parts. The issue is that there is no means to figure out how long reset was triggered. In addition the bootloader may consume an unknown amount of time during restart. Thus you would need an external real time clock.

With regard to period execution of events my favourite is the msTimer2 library. see here for some of my examples:

http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/basic-effects/persistence-of-vision/

http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/removing-flicker/heartbeat/

http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/basic-effects/lighthouses/

Answer (score 1):

My friend **delay()** and **delayMicroseconds()** will be all of the help to you.

As far as other replies are concerned.

**mills()** - Returns the number of milliseconds since the Arduino board began running the current program. This number will overflow (go back to zero), after approximately 50 days.

Refer : http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/millis

Similarly,

**micros ()** - Returns the number of microseconds since the Arduino board began running the current program. 
Refer : http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Micros

I guess you need to work on these two a little bit to work out in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below sample code.Here repeating steps for every 1ms.

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

// the timer object
SimpleTimer timer;

// a function to be executed periodically
void repeatMe() 
{
  Serial.print("Uptime (s): ");
  Serial.println(millis() / 1000);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  timer.setInterval(1000, repeatMe);
}

void loop() 
{
  timer.run();
}
```